# Do I ever need to overload a cast operator of a class?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I'm currently planning a class with some conversion functions. I just wonder when I have to overload the cast operator of a class. When I have a conversion constructor `A(B& b)` then as far as I see whenever I need to convert a B into an A, i could just use the conversion constructor.

Examples:

```
B b, c, d;
A a = b; // conversion constructor automatically called
a = A(c); // could also overload assignment operator
function_of_a((A)d); // can equally write this as function_of_a(A(d))
```

Currently I plan to use just a conversion constructor, whereas I do not see any purpose of an overloaded cast operator and I also plan to INTENTIONALLY NOT overload the assignment operator for A = B to make the conversion more obvious in the code.

Comment: Note that your conversion constructor does not allow rvalues.

Comment: Conversion constructors are part of the *destination* type's interface. Cast operators are part of the *source* type's interface. Sometimes you can't change the destination type or don't want it to have a dependency on the source type.

Comment: @chris: If no rvalue/move constructor is present, doesn't it just fall back to a normal reference/copy constructor?

Comment: @Michael, I mean rvalues of type `B`. They cannot bind to a non-const lvalue reference.

Comment: I see, I should qualify B& const.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously have to write a cast operator if you are converting to primitives or a type you have no access to - for example, `operator bool()` or `operator std::string()`.

Beyond that, it's primarily an issue of interface design. Conversion constructors are part of the destination type's interface. Cast operators are part of the source type's interface. You need to decide which interface the conversion should belong to.

For example, suppose you have a `fancy_string` class, and a dozen other classes that can be converted to `fancy_string` to produce a `fancy_string` representation. Should `fancy_string` contain conversion constructors for all of those classes? Probably not. This would make `fancy_string` dependent on all of those dozen classes, and each time you add a class that should be convertible to `fancy_string`, you would have to change `fancy_string` as well. This is terrible design. It would be far better to provide a cast operator in each of those classes, because the ability-to-convert-to-a-`fancy_string` should be part of the interface of those classes, not `fancy_string`.